# How to quote a quote with the CONCATENATE function in OOCalc

Tags: concatenation, openoffice-calc

In `OOCalc` I want to use the `CONCATENATE` function to add quotes to each string in column A.

So in cell B1 I want to do:

```
=CONCATENATE("\"",A1,"\"")
```

`OOCalc` does not like this, or without the escaping backslash.

Does anyone know how to do this, or what an alternative method might be?

Answer (score 187, accepted):

This works for me:

```
=CONCATENATE("""",A1,"""")
```

Repeating the quotes escapes them (as it does in Visual Basic, I believe), so `""""` reads as: 'one quote to start a string, one escaped quote (""), then one quote to finish the string'.

Comment: Works for Google Sheets too

Comment: When you have a complex construction like in a QUERY this methode won't work. In such cases, the @kiran answer does work   CONCATENATE(char(34); B2 ;char(34))

Comment: You can simply use ampersand `&` to concatenate too, e.g: `=""""&A1&""""`

Answer (score 41):

Use `char(34)` to get the quote character.

```
CONCATENATE(char(34); B2; char(34))
```

Comment: This one works in complex construction needed in queries

Answer (score 16):

Identical to the above but without the function:

`="""" & A1 & """"`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in 2 ways,

1. By using  **=CHAR(34)** in the places of doible quotes
   eg: =CONCATENATE("coffee",CHAR(34),"code")
2. By concatenating cell values

**Steps**

- Set the cell value as double quotes -> "
- Concatenate that cell in the string, wherever you need double quotes.
  eg: E1 = "
  F1 = =concatenate("coffee",E1,"code")

Thank you

Comment: This question has already been answered, and using a simpler method than either of your suggested options.

Comment: I implemented the methods mentioned above, but when we try to copy the data from the formatted cell, extra double quotes is appearing in the data. Hence I worked on it and found a better solution, that is what I added here. If it is not useful for you ignore it, there will be some people looking for a better solution. Thank you.

Comment: That's not how StackOverflow works, as it is a repository of knowledge you don't just ignore things.  You also provided none of the details in your comment in your answer.

Comment: I don't know why you are targeting me, after all,  I explained it clearly in the second comment. Thank you.

Comment: StackOverflow flagged your answer as low quality, I'm not targeting you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quotations marks within the double quotation marks and vice versa.